# Dynamic column in sql/jdbc query

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am a student of Computer Science. Now I am working on a project with jdbc. I have to table in database - `USER`, `ROLE`.

Where each `USER` have a one or multiple `ROLE`. I save the `ROLE.ID` (primary key or `ROLE`) in `USER.ROLE_ID` column.

In java code level I have two entity class also - `User.java` and `Role.java`. I can make the simple SQL query with joining these tables.

Please see the following queries -

**1.** Selecting `USER.NAME` and `ROLE.NAME` for `USER.NAME='admin'` -

```
SELECT USER.NAME, ROLE.NAME FROM USER, ROLE
   WHERE USER.ROLE_ID = ROLE.ROLE_ID
   AND USER.NAME='admin';
```

**2.** Selecting `USER.ID` and `ROLE.ID` for the `USER.NAME='admin'` -

```
SELECT USER.ID, ROLE.ID FROM USER, ROLE
   WHERE USER.ROLE_ID = ROLE.ROLE_ID
   AND USER.NAME='admin';
```

I have to make 2 different queries **ONLY**  for the different columns I am selecting. Here most of the query is same. My question is can I do something so that I can dynamically select different (in first case - USER.NAME, ROLE.NAME and Second case USER.ID, ROLE.ID) types of column using a single query?

Comment: You can use all those 4 columns in single query. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You will not have anything like this from JDBC.You have to write your custom function for this.

In my opinion, you should just make a function which is taking two parameters OR the same overloaded functions and then provide them arguments. 
here I am providing you some pseudo code for logic

```
        function getData(Param tableName, Param column1, Param column2){
        String sql = "SELECT "+column1+"','"+column2+"' 
                FROM `" + tableName + "` WHERE "+column1+" = "+column2;
        }

//overloaded
       function getData(Param tableName, Param column1, Param column2,Param column3){
        String sql = "SELECT "+column1+"','"+column2+"','"column3+"' 
                FROM `" + tableName + "` WHERE "+column1+" = "+column2;
        }
```

But if you are ready to use some APIs then I can suggest you two very good API to win your scenario. you should give a try to 
 [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/)
 [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)
 [Apache ddlUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/) 
 [squiggle-sql](https://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/) 
 [JaQu](http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html) 
 .

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT USER.ID, USER.NAME, ROLE.ID, ROLE.NAME FROM USER, ROLE
   WHERE USER.ROLE_ID = ROLE.ROLE_ID
   AND USER.NAME='admin';
```

?

I don't really get the question here to be honest.

Comment: if you have some knowledge of databases or JDBC , then it is not a difficult question. He wants something like prepared statement but in some dynamic fashion